# How do I draw a "tile" from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, tile

I'm trying to draw an array, but I don't know the proper way of performing that.
Here's my array.

```
int[][] map=
            {
                    {1,1,1,1,1},
                    {0,0,1,0,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,1},
                    {0,0,1,0,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,1}

            };
```

I know I'm missing alot, and I can't seem to find any answers that are understandable to a beginner coder.

Comment: What do you mean "Drawing an array?" could you give an example?

Comment: You want to somehow "print" that? With loops maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] map=
            {
                    {1,1,1,1,1},
                    {0,0,1,0,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,1},
                    {0,0,1,0,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,1}

            };

int rows = 5;
int cols = 5;
int i, j;

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
    System.out.print(map[i][j] + " ");
  }
System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: You should get the length from the map array instead of hard coding the rows and cols variables.

Comment: I built a bit more apon the code, this is what I ended up using `int[][] map=
  {
    {1,1,1,1,1},
    {0,0,1,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1},
    {0,0,1,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1}
       
  };
 int rows = 5;
 int cols = 5;
 int i, j;

 for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
   for (j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
     if(map[i][j] == 0){
      d.drawImage(voidspace,i*50,j*50,this);
     }
     if(map[i][j] == 1){
      d.drawImage(floor,i*50,j*50,this);
     }
     if(map[i][j] == 2){
      d.drawImage(wall,i*50,j*50,this);
     }
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Using a GridPane:

```
public static void printImage(idPicture, path){
        image = new Image(path);
        this.idPicture = idPicture; //in your case 0 or 1

        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j< height; j++){
                if(map[i][j] == idPicture){ //check the current id
                    imageViewMatrix[i][j] = new ImageView(image); //load the image in the matrix
                    imageViewMatrix[i][j].setPreserveRatio(true);
                    imageViewMatrix[i][j].setFitWidth(imageWidth); 
                    pane.add(imageViewMatrix[i][j], i, j); //add image to the pane
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the easiest way for me. But you have to repeat this process for each image you want to print, setting the ID and the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print them in the console then you can try loops. However you can use some magic of Java 8 too.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Started");
    int[][] map=
        {
                {1,1,1,1,1},
                {0,0,1,0,0},
                {1,1,1,1,1},
                {0,0,1,0,0},
                {1,1,1,1,1}

        };

    Arrays.asList(map).stream().forEach((a) -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));

    System.out.println("");

    Arrays.asList(map).stream().forEach((a) -> {
        String b = Arrays.toString(a);
        System.out.println(b.substring(1, b.length() - 1));
    });

    System.out.println("");

    Arrays.asList(map).stream().forEach((a) -> {
        String b = Arrays.toString(a);
        System.out.println(b.substring(1, b.length() - 1).replaceAll(",", " "));
    });
}
```

**Output**

```
Started
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

1, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 1, 0, 0
1, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 1, 0, 0
1, 1, 1, 1, 1

1  1  1  1  1
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  1  1  1
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  1  1  1
```